# Code completion C/C++ on Aptana doesn't work

Tags: c, autocomplete, aptana

I'm using aptana studio 3 with C code and when I'm writting an acces to an structure it suggests in each position what variables I can use, but for simple variables it doesn't suggests anything without press control+space.

Any idea how to change that?

Answer (score 0):

Aptana Studio doesn't include code completion for C/C++ by default. I would suggest you'll need to contact the plugin authors for C/C++ with that question.

Comment: But with control+space it does. Is there a way to do that automatically, without control+space?

Comment: aptana Studio adds special code for code completion to pop up automatically on certain languages....it's not something that can generically apply to all editors. The C/C++ plugin authors would have to add it themselves.